# Don't start WebStorm as SUDO on Linux

Tags: webstorm, sudo, jetbrains-ide

Don't start WebStorm as SUDO on Linux.

In terminal:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option
> UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be
> removed in a future release. No protocol specified No protocol
> specified No protocol specified No protocol specified No protocol
> specified No protocol specified No protocol specified No protocol
> specified No protocol specified
> [0727/120432.142061:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU
> process isn't usable. Goodbye. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

How fix this problem?

Comment: You can try to manually remove/rename [plugins directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#plugins-directory) and start WebStorm again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a common issue with JCEF on linux:
https://simpleit.rocks/linux/ubuntu/fixing-common-google-chrome-gpu-process-error-message-in-linux/
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/41722791?hl=en

Please try a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140#focus=Comments-27-4625101.0-0: either disable jcef completely by adding `-Dide.browser.jcef.enabled=false` to [vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) or uninstall/disable plugins that use JCEF (**Markdown**, **CUBA**, etc)

See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140#focus=Comments-27-4622292.0-0 for one more (possible) workaround